# Recursively DRY code,calculate days of months,Java

Tags: java, recursion, dry

How would you dry this piece of code recursively to avoid repetitions of days of the month.

I have an idea of putting a base case for January, and handling other months by recursively computing the dayOfYear from the previous month, then adding the current month to it.
Something like `if (month == 1) { ... } else { ... dayOfYear(month-1, dayOfMonth, year) ... } correct`
But I am not quite sure of the implementation, nor if this is an accurate approach.

Assuming that I have an array like this where I could store all of my days
int[] monthLengths = new int[] { 31, 28, 31, 30, ..., 31}

```
public static int dayOfYear(int month, int dayOfMonth, int year) {
if (month == 2) {
    dayOfMonth += 31;
} else if (month == 3) {
    dayOfMonth += 59;
} else if (month == 4) {
    dayOfMonth += 90;
} else if (month == 5) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30;
} else if (month == 6) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31;
} else if (month == 7) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30;
} else if (month == 8) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31;
} else if (month == 9) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31;
} else if (month == 10) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30;
} else if (month == 11) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31;
} else if (month == 12) {
    dayOfMonth += 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31;
}
return dayOfMonth;
```

}

Comment: why dont you just use the API ??

Comment: "... by recursively computing..." your code is not recursive.

Comment: why you don't want to just create static array `int[12]` and put all amount of days here?

Comment: Yes, I could try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested in other answers, you can easy avoid recursion just filling array with amount days between 1st day of year and 1 day of month.
Because from complexity point of view, recursion will takes `O(n)` and algorithm with predefined array - `O(1)`

But if you really want to use recursion, you can just fill amount of days in some prepared array and make calculation using `month` as index of array.

For example:

```
public static int[] daysOfMonth = new int[]{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

public int daysOfYear(int day, int month, int year) {
    if (month == 0) {
        return day;
    }
    //specific case for leap year
    int leapOffset = 0;
    if (month == 2) {
        if (Year.of(year).isLeap()) {
            leapOffset = 1;
        }
    }
    return daysOfYear(day + daysOfMonth[month-1] + leapOffset, month - 1, year);
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void testDay() {
    Assert.assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.FEBRUARY, 25).getDayOfYear(), daysOfYear(25, 1, 2015));
    Assert.assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2014, Month.MARCH, 25).getDayOfYear(), daysOfYear(25, 2, 2014));
    Assert.assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2013, Month.MAY, 25).getDayOfYear(), daysOfYear(25, 4, 2013));
    Assert.assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JUNE, 25).getDayOfYear(), daysOfYear(25, 5, 2012));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for mapping of months to sum of days till month, and you should add an offset depending on year.

```
private static int[] daysTillMonth = ...

public static int dayOfYear(int month, int dayOfMonth, int year) {
   return daysTillMonth[month] + dayOfMonth + month>1?yearOffset(year):0;
}

private int yearOffset(int year) {
   // implement
}
```

You could also compose an mathematic equation to just calculate this eg:

```
public static int dayOfYear(int month, int dayOfMonth, int year) {
   int n1 = (275 * month / 9)
   int n2 = ((month + 9) / 12)
   int n3 = (1 + ((year - 4 * (year / 4) + 2) / 3))
   int n = n1 - (n2 * n3) + dayOfMonth - 30
   return n;
}
```

Comment: I will try this approach, do you have any idea on how to implement it following my convention.
"I have an idea of putting a base case for January, and handling other months by recursively computing the dayOfYear from the previous month, then adding the current month to it."

Answer (score 0):

your code is going to fail in several ways...

February doesn't always have 28 days...

you need to learn to use the API that java developed for you!

on the other hand... there is nothing related to recursiveness in the code you posted... you dont even need such...

my suggestion goes:

```
public static long dayOfYear(int month, int dayOfMonth, int year) {
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth));
}
```

Comment: It is not about the API, the question is from the book I am currently going through.
Yes you are right,there we encounter a magic number, with february.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize a second array:

```
private static int[] monthLengths = new int[] { 31, 28, 31, 30, ..., 31};
private static int[] monthStart = new int[12];
static {
    for (int i = 1; i < monthStart.length; ++i) {
        monthStart[i] = monthStart[i-1] + monthLength[i-1];
    }
}
```